# Isomorphism between $\Bbb Z[X,Y ]/(2Y−1)$ and $\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2}][X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I been trying to prove that $\Bbb Z[X,Y]/(2Y−1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z[\frac{1}{2}][X]$ where $$\Bbb Z\left[\frac{1}{2}\right]=\left\{\frac{a}{2^n} : a \in \Bbb Z, n \in \Bbb N, n ≥ 0\right\}$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe look at the morphism $\mathbb Z[X,Y]\mapsto\mathbb Z[\frac12][X]$ sending $Y$ to $\frac12$.

Comment: I tried thinking about factoring power of Y by division theorem, I also found out that $(2^n)*(Y^n)=1$ but not sure what to do

Comment: A map from $\Bbb Z[X,Y]$ to $\Bbb Z[1/2][X]$ is defined by mapping $X\to X$ (instead of something else...) and $Y\to\frac 12$ (instead of...) . It is well defined. The map in the converse direction is mapping a "coefficient" $a/2^n$, $a\in\Bbb Z$, into $aY^n$, and of course $X$ into $X$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky to prove, so I'll give you a few hints and ideas. Let $A=\Bbb Z[X]$.

Define the map $$\phi:A[Y]\rightarrow A[1/2]\\\phi(f(Y))=f(1/2)$$

Then you need so show that $\ker(\phi)=(2Y-1)$. By the first isomorphism theorem you're then done.

The inclusion $(2Y-1)\subseteq\ker(\phi)$ is OK, for the other direction suppose that $f(Y)\in\ker(\phi)$. Then find $n$ such that $2^nf(Y)=g(Z)$, where $Z=2Y$. You then have that $g(1)=0$. Now use the factor theorem.

---

**Example**
Suppose that $f(Y)=4Y^4-4Y^3+21Y^2-20Y+5$, we check that $f(1/2)=0$ is true. Now compute $2^4f(Y)$, which yields $$2^4f(Y)=4(2Y)^4-4\cdot 2(2Y)^3+21\cdot 2^2 (2Y)^2-20\cdot 2^3(2Y)+5\cdot 2^4$$ Letting $Z=2Y$, we arrive at $$g(Z)=4Z^4-8Z^3+84Z^2-160Z+80$$ since $Y=1/2$ is a root of $f$, we know that $Z=1$ is a root of $g$. Therefore $g(Z)=(Z-1)h(Z)$, and so $$2^4f(Y)=(2Y-1)h(2Y)$$ you then only have to conclude that $\ker(\phi)\subseteq (2Y-1)$.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Good point! I made $A=\Bbb Z[X]$, to make it easier for notation.

Comment: Hi sorry, I don't fully understand how does the functio phi work does it send f(Y) to f(1/2) how about f(3Y-1) what does it send it to. It's my first algebra course so I don't fully get stuff apologies

Comment: @rasheda564 It's an evaluation homomorphism; it maps $Y\mapsto 1/2$. So $\phi(f(3Y-1))=f(3/2-1)=f(1/2)$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I don't also understand the converse what's g(Z)